# OEM Plug-in development

Tags: oracle, enterprise

I am new to developing plugin for Oracle enterprise manager. Am looking for good guidance to achieve my requirement. How to develop OEM plug-in? Is there any sample plug-in available in online for reference?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would suggest would be to familiarize yourself with the Oracle documentation in regards to plug-in development for Oracle Enterprise Manager.  You can find the documentation at the following location:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/doc.121/e25159/plugin_lifecycle.htm#EMPRG121

The primary functionality is built around a development tool kit that is installed within the EM application directory structure.  This toolkit acts as a translation mechanism to build the plugin within the architecture of your Oracle EM instance.  Each instance is unique when considering high availability, load balancing, repository configuration, and any infinite number of parameters.

An example that is open to the public would be the Dell OpenManage Plug-in that can be found at this location:

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/6440.dell-openmanage-plug-in-for-oracle-enterprise-manager